# ld returned 1 exit status w/ multiple definition of function

Tags: c++, heap, ld

There's probably a 2 second solution to this but I've been trying to figure it out for the past hour and it's driving me crazy.

I'm trying to link together a .cpp and .h files into a main.cpp file, so it'd run there. But I get a multiple definition of every function inside my cpp file, which in causes "ld returned 1 exit status"

The more functions I add, the more errors I get.

Here's my code:

binaryHeap.h:

```
#ifndef Binary_H
#define Binary_H

#include <vector>

class BinaryHeap{
    private:
        std::vector <int> heap;
        int left(int parent);
        int right(int parent);
        void heapifyUp(int index);
        void heapifyDown(int index);
    public:
        BinaryHeap(); //Constructor
        void insert(int element); //inserts element into heap
        void deleteMin(); // deletes minimum element
        int extractMin();
        void displayHeap();
        int size();
};

#endif //Binary_H
```

binaryHeap.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "binaryHeap.h"

BinaryHeap::BinaryHeap(){
}

void BinaryHeap::heapifyUp(int index){
    int parent = (index - 1) / 2;

    if(index != 0 && parent >= 0 && heap[parent] > heap[index]){
        int temp = heap[index];
        heap[index] = heap[parent];
        heap[parent] = temp;
        heapifyUp(parent);
    }
}



void BinaryHeap::insert(int element){
    heap.push_back(element);
    heapifyUp(heap.size() - 1);
}



void BinaryHeap::displayHeap(){
    std::vector<int>::iterator pos = heap.begin();
    while (pos != heap.end()){
        std::cout << *pos << std::endl;
        pos++;
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "binaryHeap.cpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    BinaryHeap h;
    h.insert(5);
    h.insert(2);
    h.insert(19);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the errors:

> main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of
>   `BinaryHeap::BinaryHeap()' binaryHeap.o:binaryHeap.cpp:(.text+0x0):
>   first defined here main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of`
>   BinaryHeap::BinaryHeap()' binaryHeap.o:binaryHeap.cpp:(.text+0x0):
>   first defined here main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20): multiple definition
>   of `BinaryHeap::heapifyUp(int)'
>   binaryHeap.o:binaryHeap.cpp:(.text+0x20): first defined here
>   main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xfe): multiple definition of`
>   BinaryHeap::insert(int)' binaryHeap.o:binaryHeap.cpp:(.text+0xfe):
>   first defined here main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x13e): multiple definition
>   of `BinaryHeap::displayHeap()'
>   binaryHeap.o:binaryHeap.cpp:(.text+0x13e): first defined here
>   c:/program files
>   (x86)/dev-cpp/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   binaryHeap.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section`.pdata$_ZnwyPv'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> C:\Users\~\Desktop\Coding Training\Binary Heap\Makefile.win:25: recipe
>   for target '"Binary' failed mingw32-make.exe: *** ["Binary] Error 1

Comment: You must never include a `.cpp` file.
In `main.cpp`, change the include to `binaryHeap.h`

Answer (score 3):

Extending on my comment, you must never include a `.cpp` file in any other file. What `#include` does is copy all the contents from the included file into the place you are including it. This means that the contents of `binaryHeap.cpp` are compiled twice in your code. And this is what the errors are telling you.

To resolve errors in your case - in `main.cpp`, change the include to `binaryHeap.h`.

EDIT: Adding more explanation:

**The include directive simply copies and pastes the source of the file to that spot**. So, if you included `binaryHeap.cpp` in `main.cpp`, the source of `binabyHeap` is actually being compiled twice. And, once the linker starts combining your object files, it picks up multiple definitions of whatever you had in `binaryHeap.cpp`, and raises a few errors.

Comment: You say the contents of binaryHeap.cpp are compiled twice. But I don't understand why. Does it go like this? 'main.cpp -> includes binaryHeap.h -> copies binaryHeap.cpp (since binaryHeap.cpp includes binaryHeap.h)?

Comment: @Homerdough No, it's because you included binaryHeap's **cpp** file in main.c instead of the **h**